# How to redirect to current page's sibling or subfolder page in ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I need to redirect PayPal Service to a page after it gets accepted by user. The page I want to redirect follows the following structure:

- Me.aspx
- \Paypal\Accept.aspx
- \Paypal\Cancel.aspx
- \Paypal\Finish.aspx

so if I'm on `http://localhost:63000/myfolder/me.aspx`

I want to be redirected by PayPal to `http://localhost:63000/myfolder/paypal/accept.aspx`

How?

Comment: Ok. Got it working!

I can use HttpContext.Current to get my current Url and then rewrite current page to the subdirectory and page:

    ReturnURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Replace("me", "PayPal/Accept")

If `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` is 

`http://localhost:63000/myfolder/me.aspx` 

then `ReturnURL` is 

`http://localhost:63000/myfolder/PayPal/Accept.aspx`, 

and PayPal sandbox returns properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got it working!

I can use HttpContext.Current to get my current Url and then rewrite current page to the subdirectory and page:

`ReturnURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Replace("me", "PayPal/Accept")`

If HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri is `http://localhost:63000/myfolder/me.aspx` then ReturnURL is `http://localhost:63000/myfolder/PayPal/Accept.aspx`, and PayPal sandbox returns properly.

Answer (score 0):

`ReturnURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Replace("me", "PayPal/Accept")`

If HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri is http://localhost:63000/myfolder/me.aspx then ReturnURL is http://localhost:63000/myfolder/PayPal/Accept.aspx, and PayPal sandbox returns properly.

Comment: Put it as answer here so others can find solution easily